# getline and printing with cout

Tags: c++, text

I'm trying to read a text file one line at a time and print each line to a terminal window.  I'm compiling on a mac using g++, e.g., g++ cpp3.cpp -o cpp3.

The text file looks like this:

```
20100000001 20100000001.xml
20100000002 20100000002.xml
20100000003 20100000003.xml
20100000004 20100000004.xml
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ifs("file.txt");
    string line;
    while(getline(ifs,line)) {
        getline(ifs,line);
        cout << "[ " << line << " ]" << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

I'd like the output to look like:

```
[20100000001    20100000001.xml]
[20100000002    20100000002.xml]
[20100000003    20100000003.xml]
[20100000004    20100000004.xml]
```

However, everything is printed to a single line in the terminal.  In other words, each line from the text file is written on top of the last.  Furthermore, the brackets, "[" and "]" appear to only be written once, so that it basically prints "[", then the entire contents of the file, and then "]".

So this is what the final output to the terminal looks like:

```
user$ ./cpp3
 ]10000000401   20100000004.xml

user$
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and/or how to fix the problem?

Comment: Note: you're calling getline twice in each iteration. Could you run your program's output through hexdump? (I'm guessing you have strange end-of-line characters in your source text file.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the data file - perhaps with `od -c`.

Everything written on top of each other line sounds as if you're printing `\r` (carriage return) and not `\n` (newline) in the output, maybe because the data does not contain newlines.  <s>Maybe the file comes from a Windows environment, and the `getline()` is stripping the newline, leaving carriage return at the end, and the output is not reinstating the newline?</s>

Or, maybe the file only contains `\r` line endings - in which case, the `getline()` would read the entire file as a single line, and output it as a single line.  You could demonstrate that by adding a counter to the output, incrementing it for each output line.  Your observation about 'square brackets printed once' would suggest this might be better than the stricken suggestion.  You have an `endl` in the output, which is important.

Comment: That did the trick. (The end lines were all \r...I changed them to \n and it worked fine.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `getline(ifs, line);` like this:

```
while(getline(ifs,line)) {
    cout << "[" << line << "]" << endl;
}
```

Also, you need to remove the spaces between the square brackets, otherwise the output will look like this:

```
[ 20100000001    20100000001.xml ]
[ 20100000002    20100000002.xml ]
[ 20100000003    20100000003.xml ]
[ 20100000004    20100000004.xml ]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't mean to have the two getline's.